# Positional light area size

Tags: opengl, light

I can set the size of the area of influence of a positional light? Something like the image:

[image]

I do not know if I can do this with GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION and  GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION.

Since I have not seen documentation that talks about this and what values ​​should each option.

Comment: Yes, you can. What you need to do is solve for the distances at which Linear, Constant and Quadratic attenuation reach 0. Then you take the maximum of those three distances and that is your light's radius. It is all spelled out [here](http://imdoingitwrong.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/light-attenuation/) since you were looking for some "documentation" that talks about this. Note that for practical purposes, you should clip the value long before it actually hits 0, or the light's extent could be infinite.

Comment: Oh, no, I just did a test and the radius of the light does not decrease. Any idea?